# What is wrong with this VenuesExplore?

Tags: java, foursquare

I am trying to get Venue names from the following codes but keep getting errors. Its obvious the snippet has some logical errors. How do I get it to display data?

String callbackUrl = "https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/samples/explore?client_id=6666666&v=20140101&ll=43,-79&client_secret=55555555";

```
FoursquareApi foursquareApi = new FoursquareApi(clientId, client_Secret, callbackUrl);

    Result<Recommended> result = foursquareApi.venuesExplore(ll, null, null, null, null,null,query, null, null);
        if (result.getMeta().getCode() == 200) 
    {

      for (RecommendationGroup venue : result.getResult().getGroups()) 
      {
             for(Recommendation r: venue.getItems())
             {
                CompactVenue cmp = r.getVenue();
                System.out.println(cmp.getName());
             }

      }
    } 
        else 
     {
      System.out.println("Error occured: ");
      System.out.println("  code: " + result.getMeta().getCode());
      System.out.println("  type: " + result.getMeta().getErrorType());
      System.out.println("  detail: " + result.getMeta().getErrorDetail()); 
    }
```

Nothing is displayed when the program is run. So I guess its logical error.

Comment: Can you be specific as to the exact errors you're seeing? A stack trace would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. 
For me it helped to change the venuesExplore() Method of the FoursquareApi.

```
public Result<Recommended> venuesExplore(String ll, Double llAcc, Double alt, Double altAcc, Integer radius, String section, String query, Integer limit, String basis) throws FoursquareApiException {..}
```

It seems that there is something wrong with the json parsing of the keywords. 
So I changed the:

```
 KeywordGroup keywords = (KeywordGroup) JSONFieldParser.parseEntity(KeywordGroup.class, response.getResponse().getJSONObject("keywords"), this.skipNonExistingFields);
```

to:

```
 KeywordGroup keywords = new KeywordGroup();
```

So no keywords in the result but the rest of the answer ist parsed right.